# Cyclic quadrilateral and perimeter

Tags: geometry

Find the perimeter of the square shown, I don't know how to solve it do I use pythagorean theorem?
[image]

Comment: I am desperately looking for a square...:)

Comment: I know I missed sorry the picture doesn't show I don't know why but it's a circle with a square inside (all corners touch the circle) then halfway the square is cut in half not all the way but it has 3 radical 2 and It shows a right angle

Comment: Once I reverse the radical I get 18 and I don't know what to do from there

Comment: We can't help you find the "perimeter of the square shown" if there is no square shown.

Comment: @EdithMendoza See my edit for the right syntax to inline images. If you click the "image" button in the editor, it will do just that for you.

Comment: @dxiv The ability to insert inline images (not just links to images) requires more reputation that the OP currently has. Thank you for your time to edit and do so yourself.

Comment: @amWhy You are right about inlining, thanks for pointing that out. (The original post didn't have even the link with the right syntax for some reason, causing it not to show, which prompted my previous comment.)

Answer (score 1):

Hints (for you to complete):

1) Both diagonals of a square meet at the circumscribing circle's center.

2) If a square's side's length is $\;x\;$ , then any of its two diagonals' length is $\;\sqrt2\,x\;$

Answer (score 0):

Try going this direction: draw another radius of the circle to an adjacent corner of the square. Now you have a right triangle, the length of the legs is $3\sqrt{2}$. Can you find the length of the hypotenuse? This is one of the sides of the square; multiply this length by 4 to find the perimeter.